# AppleScript can't get quoted form of api response

Tags: youtube-api, applescript, youtube-data-api

I made an AppleScript earlier today that displays the subscriber count of a YouTube for Geektools, but I wanted it to be easier for people to use and tried to make it work off the name of the file (ex. taking subcount-PewDiePie.scpt and outputting PewDiePie's sub count), and I've made the inputting the name from the file name work, but its giving me errors when I try to take the number out of the api's response

the working (original)'s code

```
set apiResponse to (do shell script "curl -s 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=PewDiePie&fields=items%2Fstatistics%2FsubscriberCount&key=AIzaSyAEQGj2ZcDrTU0ZqzteD8eDVJwB9cpmvEo'")

on returnNumbersInString(inputString)
    set s to quoted form of inputString
    do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s
    set dx to the result
    set numlist to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of words in dx
        set this_item to word i of dx
        try
            set this_item to this_item as number
            set the end of numlist to this_item
        end try
    end repeat
end returnNumbersInString

returnNumbersInString(apiResponse)
```

The broken customizable code

```
set channelName to path to me as text
set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"subcount-"}
set nameFilter to text items of channelName
set channelName to item 2 of nameFilter

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
set nameFilter to the text items of channelName
set channelName to item 1 of nameFilter

set curlLink to "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=" & channelName & "&fields=items%2Fstatistics%2FsubscriberCount&key=AIzaSyAEQGj2ZcDrTU0ZqzteD8eDVJwB9cpmvEo"
set curlCommand to "curl -s " & (quoted form of curlLink)

set apiResponse to {do shell script curlCommand}
on returnNumbersInString(inputString)
    set s to quoted form of inputString
    do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s
    set dx to the result
    set numlist to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of words in dx
        set this_item to word i of dx
        try
            set this_item to this_item as number
            set the end of numlist to this_item
        end try
    end repeat
end returnNumbersInString

returnNumbersInString(apiResponse)
```

Every time I do the second one it outputs the error

```
Can’t get quoted form of {"{
 \"items\": [
  {
   \"statistics\": {
    \"subscriberCount\": \"76957805\"
   }
  }
 ]
}"}.
```

It's failing immediately after it gets the info from the website, which doesn't make any sense because none of the code beyond how it got the website link has been changed, can anyone help me resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've enclosed your `do shell script` command in braces here:

```
set apiResponse to {do shell script curlCommand}
```

Therefore, the `apiResponse` is now a list containing an JSON string, instead of simply a JSON string.  Remove the braces so the line reads:

```
set apiResponse to do shell script curlCommand
```

Comment: thanks a ton, didn't expect that as the original works with them, but its fixed now

Comment: No, the original had regular parentheses, not curly braces.  Thank for accepting the answer.